# How to manipulate the shape of an object?

Tags: 3d, aframe

I'm new to A-Frame and with some background in SolidWorks and Blender, how do you manipulate the shape of an object? Like extrude or make chamfers? Elongate or make a curved cylinder perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Broadly, A-Frame is a tool for building interactive VR scenes on the web. It is more like Unity, and not a 3D modeling tool like Blender or Maya.

It is possible to modify geometry at runtime, using vertex manipulation ([example](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/src/primitives/a-ocean.js)). As you'll see, the code is a bit complicated. And your game or experience will be slower, because the shape manipulation is happening at runtime. Unless you're sure the manipulations need to be happening on the fly, it's better to create a model in advance with tools like Blender, then import them into A-Frame using [obj-model](https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/obj-model.html), [gltf-model](https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/gltf-model.html), or other model importer components.

You can also do basic deformations fairly easily, with syntax like this:

```
<a-entity obj-model="obj: base-model.obj"
          scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"
          rotation="0 180 0"></a-entity>
```

---

EDIT: There is also a community-made component to help with basic extrude and lathe operations: https://github.com/JosePedroDias/aframe-extrude-and-lathe